# Reading from file containing integer and character

Tags: c

I have a file like that:

```
5

a,b,c,d,e

a,b

b,c

d,e

a,c

e,e

3

1,2,3

1,2

2,1

3,3

10

a,b,c,d,e

a,a

b,b

c,c

d,d

e,e

a,b

b,a

c,a

d,a

e,a
```

expected output:

```
n

(a,b) (b,c) (d,e) (a,c) (e,e)

n

(1,2) (2,1) (3,3)
```

I mean, I will write n to the file instead of the  integer number and I will list the other underlined elements side by side.How can I perform a reading from the file?

I want to put them in an array because I need to compare these subsets later (a, b -> if (a == b)).

Comment: Please show your code and explain how exactly it doesn't work

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do exactly, and show us what you already tried so far

Comment: Why do you think you need an array?  You clearly need some sort of data structure, and I would guess (it's not really clear what you're trying to do, so I have to guess) that an array is not the correct structure to use.

Comment: If you click on my tags, you can see my work on this subject yesterday. I put the characters into the 2d string array using fscanf. However, this result turned out to be wrong because I cannot assign the numbers with more than one digit to the 2d string array.

Comment: Because these are a subset and I want to check if this subset is reflexive.So ı want to use array for that.